# Grails / GORM withCriteria search toString()

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, filter, grails-orm

I am displaying a table with `User`objects. The displayed information are:

```
User.firstName
User.lastName
User.email
```

but displayed by using `user.toString()` which results in the following output:

```
Gordon, Tomas (gordon.tomas@company.com)
Hanks, Jessica (hanks.jessica@company.com)
```

I want to have a filter on this list to allow people to search for specific users. These are the requirements:

```
1) 1 search field only
2) generic text input
```

currently i do the following to update the list, wheras `owner` is the input:

```
def user // input as string from the search field

def potentialUsers = User.withCriteria {
        or {
            ilike("firstName", '%' + user + '%')
            ilike("lastName", '%' + user + '%')
            ilike("email", '%' + user + '%')
        }
    }
```

this works very well when there is `only 1 word` of input.

what I however expect is that people will search like this:

- 'tom'
- 'gordon tomas'
- 'jessica@company hanks'
- 'tomas gordon'
- ... and so on

the best solution in my eyes would be to search directly in `toString()` but I have not figured out how to do so..

any ideas on how to filter that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have 2 options here: do it quick or do it right.

Quick) add a field to your domain class to contain the concatenation of the field values you want to search, like `User.concatenated = 'Gordon Tomas gordon.tomas@company.com'`. then you can fire your search like:

```
def potentialUsers = User.withCriteria {
  user.split( /\s+/ ).each{  
    ilike 'concatenated', '%' + it + '%'
  }
}
```

Right) use `Lucene` or a `Lucene`-based proper full-text search framework, like `hibernate-search` or `grails search plugin` or `elastic search` to index your fields, so you can fire the complex multi-word queries

Comment: thank you. the first way is for sure too ugly ;) i will try one of the plugins. which would you recommend on experience?

Comment: It depends on the complexity of your needs. I started with the `searchable plugin` which was good for the simple tasks, then moved to use the Lucene API directly